# ImageBlock Module- Responsive/Fluid images

Tags: 7, blocks, media, theming

I am using the ImageBlock Module to upload/insert images into a block, which works great! However I am designing a responsive/fluid website. I have no problem with this if the image is stated in CSS, but for some reason I can not get the ImageBlock to treat the image that was uploaded as responsive/fluid.

How can the image that I uploaded to the ImageBlock I created, be responsive/fluid in a website that is designed to be fluid?

Thanks!

Comment: `img { max-width: 100%; height: auto; }`?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. In order to make a image that is a part of a imageblock, responsive/fluid, you need to:

1.) Use firebug to find the image block class for the imageblock.
2.) For me I added this to CSS

```
#block-imageblock-### .imageblock-image{
    width:100%;


}
```

This will make your image that you've uploaded into a ImageBlock responsive/fluid to any screen resolution